# How use feeds importer to pull inline images into node page

Tags: feeds

I've looked at the [feeds image grabber](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_imagegrabber) module, but it sounds like this will place the images in associated fields on the node. The client really wants the images to be inline. I'm using Feeds, Feeds Importer with the Common syndication parser. The field I'm mapping to is Text format: Full HTML.

This seems like it should be a solved process, I'm just not sure what direction to take.

Comment: Did you try this solution? http://www.radcampaign.com/blog/extending-drupal-feeds-import-inline-images

Comment: that looks promising. honestly, this was so long ago i've switched jobs and actually can't remember who the client was or what i did to solve the problem.